# Programmatically sync Android app from MS.NET

Tags: android, .net

A MS.NET application needs to synchronize (read/write) with an Android app. The Android app persists its data in a SQLite database in its private storage (somthing like package_name/data....) and I need access to it from .NET.

Any hint on how to grab that database from .NET? Will I see an emulated serial connection? Or are there some APIs to do thar?

Thank you in advance, regards

Comment: Its going to be a lot more involved.  Only the app itself can access the db.  Either the app needs to poll for updates, or the app needs to download updates in response to a push message.

Comment: Thank you Sechan. But i was wondering, how a software like Samsung Kies can do all the synchronization process. And if I could ask the Android app developer to put the db not in the private folder but somewhere else? Could it be helpful?